# Linux command to print all jsons of same key

Tags: json, jq

I have json as a string "Str"

```
"{
  "A": {
    "id": 4
  },
  "B": {//Something},
  "C": {
    "A": {
      "id": 2
    }
  },
  "E": {
    "A": null
  },
  "F": {//Something}
}"
```

I wanted all non null values of "A" which can be repeated anywhere in json. I wanted output like all contents of "A"

```
{"id": 4}
{"id": 2}
```

Can you please help me with Linux command to get this ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `jq` or other syntax aware parser this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of line oriented ones use a tool which is capable of parsing JSON values syntax wise. An example using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
$ json_value='{"A":{"id":4},"B":{"foo":0},"C":{"A":{"id":2}},"E":{"A":null},"F":{"foo":0}}'
$
$ jq -c '..|objects|.A//empty' <<< "$json_value"
{"id":4}
{"id":2}
```

```
..            # list nodes recursively
| objects     # select objects
| .A // empty # print A's value if present.
```

Comment: Hi. Is there any way to print only last occurrence of "A" ?. Like in above example, only {"id": 2} should be printed.

Comment: @Sandeep `last(..|objects|.A//empty)` will do that